# iOS - Open browser before going to background

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiapplicationdelegate

I'm writing following code that opens browser when app will be going to background:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
     Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
     */
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
}
```

but its not opening. Any suggestions?

Can I open browser in "applicationWillResignActive" or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code looks fine so I guess that iOS won't let you do it. Your app has been told to go into the background - you don't get to open new apps!

PS :

Why would you ever want to do this - surely this will just really really annoy the user?

Comment: Then it's your job as a developer to push back to your boss/client that it's a bad requirement (though this is often easier said than done). I'd just tell them that Apple won't let you do it :)

Comment: ..or better yet, the OS won't let you.